# store nested object chain in a variable

Tags: php

so lets say i have a object like this

```
 {
      "status": "AlreadyVerified"
 }
```

and i want to store propert key in variable so i can access property using that variable like

```
$key = 'status';
echo $object->$key
```

but what if i have a nested object like

```
{
  "extra_info": {#305 ▼
    +"status": "AlreadyVerified"
  }
}
```

this wouldn't work

```
$key = 'extra_info->status';
echo $object->$key
```

how can i store nested object chain in a variable so i can access its property using that variable  ?

preferably some way that works for both nested and flat objects (i guess that's what the're called !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible by write helper function like this:

```
function deepFind($o, $key) {
    $key = explode('->', $key);
    $value = $o;    
    foreach ($key as $i=>$k) {
        if (is_object($value) && isset($value->{$k})) {
            $value = $value->{$k};
        } elseif (is_array($value) && isset($value[$k])) {
            $value = $value[$k];
        } elseif ($i == count($key) - 1) {
            $value = null;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Usage:

```
$o = (object)[
  "extra_info" => (object)[
    "status" => "AlreadyVerified"
  ]
];

echo deepFind($o, 'extra_info->status');
```

[Online demo](https://glot.io/snippets/f4x5r33zpj)

Comment: The question at hand shows an object nested in an object.

Comment: Sort of, `echo deepFind($o, 'extra_info[status]');` and other array variants fail.

Comment: `echo deepFind($o, 'extra_info->status');`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, albeit potentially insecure depending on where `$key` comes from:

```
<?php
$object = new stdClass();

$object->extra_info = new stdClass();

$object->extra_info->status = 'AlreadyVerified';

$key = 'extra_info->status';

eval( 'echo $object->'.$key.';' );
```

Output:

> AlreadyVerified

---

Additionally, if you wanted to parse `$key` then you could use a recursive function to access the nested value.

Comment: thanx , im going to try it ... $key is stored in db so and is provided by administrator so its ok i guess

Comment: yes thanx im going to upvote  but im going to go with @brevis  method cuz i dont like eval ... thanx again